# SQL Extract list where instances fall outside multiple, varying date windows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Forgive the formatted "table" -- not sure how to add one.  I have two tables.  A transaction table:

```
 **Member**--**Service Date**- **Order Number**
    - 1 ----- 1/15/2013 -----   651
    - 2 ----- 2/2/2013 -----    258
    - 1 ----- 9/15/2013 -----   113
    - 1 ----- 11/1/2013 -----   728
    - 2 ----- 3/3/2013 -----    309
    - 3 ----- 1/1/2013 -----    739
    - 4 ----- 11/30/2013 -----  226
    - 3 ----- 7/6/2013 -----    978
    - 3 ----- 8/7/2013 -----    266
    - 4 -----  4/1/2013 -----   198
    - 4 ----- 12/1/2013 -----   611
```

And an eligibility table, with multiple date ranges per member:

```
**Member**--**Elig. Begin**--**Elig. End**
    - 1 ----  1/1/2013 ---- 5/31/2013
    - 1 ----  8/1/2013 ---- 10/31/2013
    - 2 ---- 3/1/2013 ----  6/30/2013
    - 2 ---- 7/1/2013 ----  12/31/2013
    - 3 ---- 1/1/2013 ----  7/31/2013
    - 3 ---- 9/1/2013 ----  12/31/9999
    - 4 ---- 11/1/2013 ---- 12/31/9999
```

My objective is to return those instances in which an order was processed outside of the varying ranges of eligibility, given that the ranges change/occur multiple times per member, with multiple orders per member, I'm stumped.  My desired output from the above tables would be this:

```
**Member**--**Service Date**--**Order Number*
    - 2 ---- 2/2/2013 ----  258
    - 1 ---- 11/1/2013 ---- 728
    - 3 ---- 8/7/2013 ----  266
    - 4 ---- 4/1/2013 ----  198
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you all very much.

Best,

Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways of doing it, but one which seems to be easier to follow is using EXISTS, like this

```
SELECT Member, [Service Date], [Order Number]
FROM [transaction table] as tt
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT * 
    FROM [eligibility table] as et 
    WHERE tt.Member=et.Member and tt.[Service Date] BETWEEN et.[Elig Begin] and et.[Elig End])
```